# What power does the "Translations" section in Trademarks have?

Tags: trademark, name, translation

I have seen that someone trademarked their last name, "ABULAFIA". This last name is very ancient and appears in many scripts and translations dating back 1000 years. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abulafia_(surname)) page for this surname has the translation for the name, with some history and background.

The translation of the name is essentially, 'Father of Health" or equivalent. The person who registered this trademark holds a similar variant of the surname. But in the trademark's form it is stated that the Word Mark has no translation in other languages.

It seems that the trademarks are centered around the food industry.  If someone with the same surname opens a food place, will the current trademark holder have much success in court? (basis on the fact that it is a common surename, and it has a translation).

- Abu or Abou (أبو abū), literally "father" but also carrying the
  meaning "owner",
- al or el (الـ), or simply l if the preceding word ends with a vowel, to which it attaches itself, is the definite article
  equivalent to "the", and
- Afiyya or Afia (عافية ʿāfiya), literally "health, wellbeing" but also carrying the meaning "power".

Answer (score 1):

You do not breach a trademark by using your own name. If your name happens to by Disney and you want to open a film studio, you can call it Disney and no one can stop you.

Comment: Are there related cases in this area?

Comment: I believe there's a case where a model sued a pornstar who was using her name, turned out the pornstar's real name was actually the same as the model's name. So the suit was dropped.

Comment: There was a lawsuit in Finland between the family-owned coffee company Paulig and the family's coffee-shop magnate son Robert, over whether Robert could put his last name on the coffee bags he was selling. The ruling, as I recall, was that Robert had a sufficiently distinct and strong brand for his product that using his surname didn't infringe on Paulig-the-company's trademark.